# last-child CSS selector not working in GAS with HtmlService?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-caja

I have a script doGet where I use the HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile service to render a html file.

In the HTML template have a style entry in the header part:

```
<style>
  .subtopicp { margin: 5px 7px 5px 7px; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
  .subtopicp:last-child { border-bottom: none;}
</style>
```

this works when I paste the evalueted HTML code in a file but in a GAS web app the `.subtopicp:last-child` line is never recognized.

Are CSS selectors like `:last-child`  not usable in GAS HtmlService at all or is there a workaround for such things in Caja sanitized web apps?

Answer (score 0):

`:last-child` is not in Caja's whitelist. You can [request](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/entry) that it be added.